# Struct 'ViewBuilder' requires that 'EmptyTableRowContent<V> confirm to View:

Tags: swiftui

The above error occurs at the point of the picker that I am creating.  I am trying to set a default value from a from a @Bindable class property.

Expanding the error in Xcode doesn't really help me

```
Requirement from conditional conformance of 'Section<TableHeaderRowContent<V, Text>, Content, EmptyTableRowContent<V>>' to 'View' (SwiftUI.Section)
```

So my Picker is defined below in the context of the full View.  Note the call site of the parent view is a simply - EditGreetingCardView(greetingCard: Bindable(greetingCard!)).

```
struct EditGreetingCardView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext

    @Query(sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\EventType.eventName)
         ]) var events: [EventType]
    
    @Bindable private var greetingCard: GreetingCard
    
    init(greetingCard: Bindable<GreetingCard>) {
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen,
            .font: UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 35)!]
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.systemGreen,
            .font: UIFont(name: "ArialRoundedMTBold", size: 20)!]
        UINavigationBar.appearance().standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        UINavigationBar.appearance().compactAppearance = navBarAppearance
        
        _greetingCard = greetingCard
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section("Details") {
                    Picker("Select type", selection: $greetingCard.eventType) {
                        Text("Unknown Event")
                            .tag(Optional<EventType>.none) //basically added empty tag and it solve the case
                        
                        if events.isEmpty == false {
                            Divider()
                            
                            ForEach(events) { event in
                                Text(event.eventName)
                                    .tag(Optional(event))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
            .navigationTitle(greetingCard.cardName ?? "Card Not Named")
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on the picker line.  My Bindable is defined as
`@Bindable private var greetingCard: GreetingCard`
And the Class is:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData
import UIKit

/// This is used to build a gallery of Greeting Cards

@Model
final class GreetingCard: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var cardName: String?
    @Attribute(.externalStorage) var cardFront: Data?
    var eventType: EventType?
    var cardManufacturer: String?
    var cardURL: URL?
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Card.cardFront) var cards: [Card]? = []
    
    init(cardName: String?, cardFront: Data?, eventType: EventType? = nil, cardManufacturer: String? = nil, cardURL: URL?) {
        self.cardName = cardName
        self.cardFront = cardFront ?? UIImage(named: "frontImage")!.pngData()!
        self.eventType = eventType
        self.cardManufacturer = cardManufacturer
        self.cardURL = cardURL
    }
    
    /// A helper value that exposes the card as an Image either a blank image or the value of the image from the realted GreetingCard
    func cardUIImage() -> UIImage {
        let defaultImage: UIImage = UIImage(data: (cardFront)!) ?? UIImage(named: "frontImage")!
        return defaultImage
    }
}
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
In particular, where do you have your `@Bindable` and how do you pass this from the parent view into the child view.
Also what is `events`. Note your typo, you should have `.tag(Optional(event))`, not `events`

Comment: As mentioned, you have a typo and it’s preferred to use the id of model type as the tag rather than the model object itself.

Comment: I have updated the code above, Hopefully that helps.  I am using this exact same approach for another view (and SwiftData Class) and it works fine without the same message.  It also has the same Init and relationship.

Comment: OK, definitely something in the larger view.  If I remove all content except for the picker it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue was not the view itself, but many different problems caused by SwiftData, CoreData Optionals, and Binding in TextField.  The following blog post really helped me understand and resolve my code: [CoreData and Bindings](https://alanquatermain.me/programming/swiftui/2019-11-15-CoreData-and-bindings/)

So I restructured my SwiftData class, to have default values to all properties, thereby removing the optionals.  The View now works fine with the following code:

```
struct EditGreetingCardView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) var modelContext
    @Bindable private var greetingCard: GreetingCard
    @State var frontImageSelected: Image? = Image("frontImage")
    @State var shouldPresentCamera = false
    @State var frontPhoto = false
    @State var captureFrontImage = false
    
    @Query(sort: [
        SortDescriptor(\EventType.eventName)
    ]) var events: [EventType]
    
    init(greetingCard: Bindable<GreetingCard>) {
        _greetingCard = greetingCard
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            //        VStack {
            Section {
                Picker("Select type", selection: $greetingCard.eventType) {
                    Text("Unknown Event")
                        .tag(Optional<EventType>.none) //basically added empty tag and it solve the case
                    
                    if events.isEmpty == false {
                        Divider()
                        
                        ForEach(events) { event in
                            Text(event.eventName)
                                .tag(Optional(event))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Section("Details") {
                TextField("Description", text: $greetingCard.cardName)
                TextField("Manufacturer", text: $greetingCard.cardManufacturer)
                TextField("Website", text: $greetingCard.cardURL)
            }
            
            Section("Card Image") {
                ZStack {
                    Image(uiImage: greetingCard.cardUIImage())
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .shadow(radius: 10 )
                    Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .shadow(radius: 10)
                        .frame(width: 200)
                        .onTapGesture { self.frontPhoto = true }
                        .actionSheet(isPresented: $frontPhoto) { () -> ActionSheet in
                            ActionSheet(
                                title: Text("Choose mode"),
                                message: Text("Select one."),
                                buttons: [ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Camera"), action: {
                                    self.captureFrontImage.toggle()
                                    self.shouldPresentCamera = true
                                }),
                                          ActionSheet.Button.default(Text("Photo Library"), action: {
                                              self.captureFrontImage.toggle()
                                              self.shouldPresentCamera = false
                                          }),
                                          ActionSheet.Button.cancel()])
                        }
                        .sheet(isPresented: $captureFrontImage) {
                            ImagePicker(
                                sourceType: self.shouldPresentCamera ? .camera : .photoLibrary,
                                image: $frontImageSelected,
                                isPresented: self.$captureFrontImage)
                        }
                }
                .frame(width: 230, height: 230)
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle(greetingCard.cardName)
    }
}
```